# A Question in Rudin PMA chapter 9

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $f$ is a differentiable mapping of a *connected* open set $E\subset \Bbb{R}^n$ into $\Bbb{R}^m$ and if $f'(x)=0$ for every $x\in E$ prove that $f$ is constant in E.

How can this be done without using convexity? I'm trying to use that $f'(x)=0 \implies f$ is constant in open balls which are convex to show $A=E$ where $A=\{x\in E \mid f(x)=f(x_0\}$ where $x_0$ is fixed. Is there another way to do this with minimal use of connectedness or convexity?

Comment: How do you prove this in the one-dimensional case? (Answer: the mean-value theorem. Adapt this approach to the problem at hand.)

Comment: If you don't want to cover $E$ with open balls on which $f$ is constant, then you could try this. Let $x,y\in E$. Then there is a differentiable path $\gamma : [0,1]\to E$ from $x$ to $y$, so $(f\circ\gamma)'=0$ and $f\circ\gamma$ is constant. The hard part is showing the existence of $\gamma$ - here you will need to use connectedness and the "open and closed" trick again.

Comment: I don't think it's too much work to see that a ball is convex in a euclidean space. This is the approach I would recommend. Also, looking at the behavior of a function on a path is a trick you would do well to learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First show that $f$ is locally constant using the mean value theorem.

Then choose $x_0 \in E$ and let $F = \{x \in E | f(x) = f(x_0) \}$. Then $F$ is closed because $f$ is continuous, and open because $f$ is locally constant. However, since $E$ is connected, the only subsets of $E$ that are both open and closed are $E$ and $\emptyset$. Hence $F = E$.

Comment: A more intuitive proof (to me) is to show that if $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open and connected, then in fact it is path connected. In fact it is path connected by a smooth path (or a finite collection of line segments if you prefer). Then show that if $\gamma$ is a path joining any two points in $E$, then $f(\gamma(1)) = f(\gamma(0))$. The above proof is less 'constructive', but more concise.